# ExtJs 6 checkcolumn listener when cell's red flag is removed or known to stay

Tags: extjs, callback, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am having a table with checkcolumn (*Ext.grid.column.Check*) items.

When (un-)checking an item an ajax callback is immediately done to the backend.

There is two outcomes:
- successfully handling by the backend and the flag disappears, or
- the flag stays. but it is not determinable from user's point of view when that happened.

During the call a small red flag is shown on top left corner of the cell.
If the backend call returns successful the red flag gets removed; otherwise it stays.

Now I need a listener callback for when the ajax call has returned.

There is a bunch of listeners at https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Check.html#events but I do not find the one helping me with my problem.

Why I ask? - I want to show a page wide unmodifiable wait layer/icon during the backend call. The layer must be removed after the call has finished no matter how successfully it did finish.

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkcolumn` is part of a `grid` which is bound to a `store`. The `checkcolumn` does not have anything to do with the synchronization itself. Synchronization is part of the `store`. Obviously, since you tell us that sync is executed whenever you click on a checkbox, you have set the store to [`autoSync: true`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.ProxyStore.html#cfg-autoSync), which limits your options because it hides the work and does not intuitively allow you to add a sync callback to the store.

If you do the sync manually, you can add a callback to the sync:

```
store.sync({
    callback: function(batch) {
        ...
    }
});
```

This callback is executed when the XmlHttpRequests are finished, regardless of their outcome; and you can then check the state of each batch or the state of the store and act accordingly (e.g. MessageBox).

Also, you could override the [`onEndUpdate`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/ProxyStore.js.html#line865) function on your store, and add the callback option to the sync that is triggered there.

Answer (score 0):

For solving my issue I did have to use *Ext.data.Store* implementation.
Checking on the `operation` value solved it for me.

```
Ext.define('MyDataStorage', {

  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  ...
  autoLoad: true,
  autoSync: true,
  remoteFilter: true,
  remoteSort: true,

  listeners: {

      update: function(store, record, operation, modifiedFieldNames, details, eOpts) {

         if ( 'commit' == operation ) {
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#someList')[0].doSomething();
         }
      },
  }
});
```

The `autoSync:true` was set like [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827295) guessed. I was not able to do the sync  differently.

*Thank you [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827295) for your expertise and hint.*